# EV SSL on Ubuntu 14.04 Digital Ocean Droplet (running sentora)

Tags: ssl, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, sentora

Here's a short explanation of the situation:

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 VPS from DigitalOcean and I'm trying to install an EV SSL  from Comodo for my domain. I've installed Sentora which uses Apache - 2.4.3 which a bit older than 2.4.8 (there's a small difference to what we enter into the VirtualHost configuration file using the tutorial I've used)

The tutorial I've followed:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority

The problem:
When I go to the https:// page, my site doesn't load. It loads http:// tho (In the image attached below you can see the virtualhost conf file and the ports listening),
Apache still listens on port 80 instead of 443, I've trying opening the port manually but that still doesnt work as you can see.

[image: Open ports and virtualhost config file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the Apache 000-default.conf as per digital ocean's tutorial won't do anything when using Sentora control panel unless you overwrite the Virtual Host Setting in Sentora.

Go to Sentora -> Admin -> Module Admin -> Apache

Scroll to bottom to Override a Virtual Host Setting -> Select your Domain / Sub-Domain

- In Port Override box enter : 443
- ensure that the checkbox labelled Forward Port 80 to Overriden Port: is checked
- In Custom entry field copy and paste:

  SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateFile /dir/certificate.crt

  SSLCertificateKeyFile /dir/certificate.key

  SSLCACertificateFile /dir/certificate.ca_bundle

Then Save vhost.
In a few minutes your SSL will get enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your netstat command doesn't show anything listening on `:443` . Did you restart Apache after your config edit ?

Run this command to check what files you are including in Apache exactly : `httpd -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES`

The `Redirect permanent` should be removed, it is looping on itself.

Comment: I have restarted Apache multiple times, also trying enabling and disabling ssl using a2enmod ssl & a2dismod ssl to no luck. Also removed the redirect, still the same. I couldn't run the httpd command, I tried running throught apachectl but the arguments are invalid.

Comment: httpd -t command must work or you have a serious installation problem.

Comment: I can run it using the apachectl prefix, but it outputs "Action 'httpd -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES' failed. The Apache error log may have more information."

Comment: I checked the Apache error log file but didn't see any problems.

Comment: No way, apachectl is for starting/stopping the service, and there must be a binary named httpd on your server, please try to find it.